# Hasura: How can I add a new detail row while implicitly setting up the foreign key to its parent?

Tags: hasura

I'm trying to insert a new child row into the "many" side of a 1:M relationship in Hasura, but would prefer not to have to explicitly assign the foreign key id.

I've seen examples here for how to insert both the child and a new parent at the same time, but I'm trying to insert a new child row and point it to an **existing** parent without having to explicitly specify the id.

The SQL below illustrates what I'm trying to do.  Is there a way to replicate this effect using hasura's generated gql resolvers?

Assuming

```
INSERT INTO foo (type) VALUES
    ( 'red' ),
    ( 'green' ),
    ( 'blue' );
```

How can I

```
INSERT INTO bar (description, foo_id) VALUES
    ( 'testing',     (SELECT id from foo WHERE type='blue') ),
    ( 'another row', (SELECT id from foo WHERE type='red' ) );
```

using GQL syntax with hasura's generated resolvers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the specifics of your application (esp. limitations around permissions), it might be possible by leveraging `upsert` mutation - https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/mutations/upsert.html

Here's an example, with the data models specified in the question:

```
mutation Test {
  insert_foo_one(
    object: {
      type: "blue", 
      bars: {
        data: [
          { description: "testing" }
        ]
      }
    }, 
    on_conflict: {
      constraint: foo_type_key, # added this constraint
      update_columns: type, 
      where: {type: {_eq: "blue"}}
    }
  ) {
    id
    type
    bars {
      description
      id
    }
  }
}
```

No reference to id, except in the responses (which could be omitted as well). It's possible to dynamically construct and pass in the type "blue", "red", etc. and the description. Doesn't seem possible to do 1 insert tho for two different foo values at the same time tho.

Another option might be to use Custom Actions - https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/actions/index.html

Comment: This looks like it will do the trick.  This will also update the parent "foo" table's "type" column to the same value it was before.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: @JasonJones that's correct, it will also update the parent -- in an upsert, the update_columns cannot be empty. But you could constrain that further w/permissions saying it whatever value being sent from the client must column equal (`_ceq` operator) the current db value. Then say only admins can set foo, and all other users can create bars against it. (Thanks for using foo & bar :p)